# Visual Basic - Drawing an image on a panel underneath an object

Tags: visual-studio-2010, transparency, drawimage

I have a panel with multiple pictureboxes in it, which when clicked change them image in the picturebox. At the same time when the image is changed, I want it to draw the same image on the panel at the location of the picturebox. This way, when a transparent object is overlaid on top of the pictureboxes (showing the parent, in this case the panel) it appears as if the pictureboxes are still there. Not sure how to go about doing this,

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will achieve what you're looking for...

```
Private Sub Panel1_Paint(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Panel1.Paint
    For Each pb As PictureBox In Panel1.Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox)()
        If Not IsNothing(pb.Image) Then
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(pb.Image, pb.Location)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```